# Determine if an app was installed from an iOS 8 app bundle?

Tags: ios

iOS 8 introduced "app bundles", where you can allow a user to pay for and install several apps at the same time. I'm trying to do some analytics to see how users may be using these apps differently if they installed the bundle rather than the separate apps. Can I tell from within an app whether the app was installed as part of a bundle?

(Note that I'm assuming the other apps in the bundle are also installed; I know how to determine that. But it doesn't tell me whether the *bundle* was installed.)